# Can't use minify at script section on ionic 2

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2, package, config

I want to add the minify command to use in Ionic 2 project. After reading of this manual https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts. I add the needed section to package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "minify": "ionic-app-scripts minify",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
}
```

Run **npm run minify**. And occurs a error:

```
> MobileSiteApp@ minify D:\denwerready\-readyscript\modules\mobilesiteapp\appsou
rce
> ionic-app-scripts minify

[14:13:05]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.2
[14:13:05]  minify started ...
[14:13:05]  cleancss started ...
[14:13:05]  uglifyjs started ...
[14:13:06]  ionic-app-script task: "minify"
[14:13:06]  Error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in undefined at li
ne undefined, col undefined, pos
            undefined
Error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in undefined at line undefined
, col undefined, pos undefined
    at new BuildError (D:\denwerready\-readyscript\modules\mobilesiteapp\appsour
ce\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at taskReject (D:\denwerready\-readyscript\modules\mobilesiteapp\appsource\n
ode_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\worker-process.js:36:22)
    at D:\denwerready\-readyscript\modules\mobilesiteapp\appsource\node_modules\
@ionic\app-scripts\dist\worker-process.js:14:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "minify"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MobileSiteApp@ minify: `ionic-app-scripts minify`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MobileSiteApp@ minify script 'ionic-app-scripts minify'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the MobileSiteApp package
,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts minify
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs MobileSiteApp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls MobileSiteApp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Чубзик\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-26T11_13_06
_136Z-debug.log
```

How to fix it? I have lastest Ionic v.3 and ionic-app-script v.1.3.2